# Не меняются иконки C++

Tags: c++, winapi

Вообщем вот фрагмент кода, код себя ведет не очень понятно, все как бы хорошо, но иконка не меняется при наступлении 19 часов(а так должно быть)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
bool night=true;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_USER:
        if (lParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
            if (MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Завершить работу?"), TEXT("Ы"), MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
                DestroyWindow(window);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(window, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
void Timing() 
{

    SYSTEMTIME time;
    GetLocalTime(&time);

    int Hour = 19 - time.wHour; 
    int Min = 60 - time.wMinute; 
    if (Hour <= 0 || Hour >= 13) 
    {
        SetBrightness(NULL, 90); 
        night = false;

    }
    else
    {
        --Hour;
        Hour = Hour * 360000; 
        Min = Min * 6000; 
        int sleep = Min + Hour;
        Sleep(sleep); 
        SetBrightness(NULL, 90); 
        night = false;
    }

}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    std::thread thr(Timing); 
    thr.detach();
MSG message;

    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
        if (night = false)
        {
            Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &Icon);
            Icon.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("night.ico"), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            Icon.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON;
            Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &Icon);
        }
        else
        {
            Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &Icon);
            Icon.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("day.ico"), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            Icon.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON;
            Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &Icon);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А почему она должна измениться?

Comment: Между прочим, вы (пытаетесь) меняете иконку при приходе каждого сообщения и нигде не проверяете наличие ошибок.

Comment: Кроме того, поток у вас отваливается при вызове `thr.detach();
`

Comment: @VTT у меня почему-то ничего не отваливается, не знаю в чем проблема, может я что-то не так делаю

Comment: @spais Он отваливается потому что вы вызываете `thr.detach();`, вместо этого по окончании работы надо вызвать `thr.join();`, предварительно уведомив поток о том, что он должен завершить работу.

Comment: @VTT все, понял о чем вы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум замените

```
if (night = false)
```

на

```
if (!night)
```

да и переменную `night` следовало бы объявить как `volatile`..

Comment: Не обратил внимание на само условие, спасибо )

Comment: @VTT потому что это UB иначе будет. Вот почему бы глядя только на функцию main не закешировать night?

Comment: @AndrioSkur Что-то я не заметил там еще и `thread`, ну а в таком случае `volatile` от UB не спасает. Тогда надо `std::atomic`

Comment: @Andrio Skur - И с чего это вдруг там возникнет UB? И зачем вдруг глобальные переменные требуется объявлять как `volatile`? Они как бы по определению могут измениться за пределами данной единицы компиляции.

Comment: @freim Они могут изменяться за пределами данной единицы компиляции, но не в другом потоке. Но `volatile` от этого не спасает.

Comment: @VTT, с этим я согласен, конечно, но мы же говорим о конкретном случае, а не вообще (я, впрочем, сам в начале слишком обобщил, виноват). Вот в данном конкретном коде я не вижу возможности для компилятора закешировать эту переменную. Не говоря уже о том странном заявлении, что тут каким-то образом из-за нее может произойти UB.

Comment: @freim А при чем тут "закешировать"? В функции `Timing`, выполняющейся в другом потоке, без синхронизации выполняется строчка `night = false;`, а в основном потоке без синхронизации выполняется `if (night = false)`. Эти две строки могут выполняться одновременно - это состояние гонки, оно всегда является неопределенным поведением.

Comment: @VTT, ага, наперегонки присваивают false, тут-то беда и случится. :) Даже в исправленном случае ничего плохого не призойдет, хотя формально без синхронизации так делать нельзя. Формально ошибка, но как минимум в данной системе и архитектуре, такое обращение к булевой переменной не приведет ни к чему плохому совершенно.

Comment: @freim Надеяться, что неопределенное поведение обойдет вас стороной, чревато...

Comment: @VTT, не в данном случае, посмотрите на код внимательно. Вне зависимости от наличия или отсутствия UB код будет нормально работать.

Comment: @freim Наличие в коде UB делает невозможным судить о поведении этого кода.

Comment: @VTT, совсем необязательно. UB совсем не означает, что компьютер взорвется, под этим термином понимается масса ситуаций, многие из которых вполне безобидные. Как в данном случае. Возможно, на свете существует архитектура, в которой такой код может иметь какие-то нежелательные эффекты (и стандарт исходит из такой возможности), но в данном случае речь исключительно о Windows программе под архитектуру x86.

Comment: @freim Undefined Behavior - это вполне конкретный термин в стандарте для обозначения ситуаций, для которых стандарт не предусматривает никаких требований. Взрыв компьютера как раз вполне может быть результатом UB. Почитайте хорошую статью по теме: [Неопределенное поведение может приводить к путешествиям во времени](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633/).